# Is it possible to install MySQL5.7 on Debian 10/buster?

Tags: mysql, debian, mysql5, debian-buster

I have tried two times and it always fails. According to [this little guy](https://superuser.com/a/1481211/551818) debian stopped packaging mysql-client as of buster. I tried to cope with it by installing MariaDB but I struggle to find a useful tutorial. Then I tried with [this tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mysql-on-debian-10/) but I get the following error when installing the client:

```
miked@debian:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.34-1debian10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So is it possible to install mysql5.7 on Debian10 buster or should I install a debian9 server?

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install the package on your Debian system, which will add PPA file to your system. During the installation of MySQL apt config package, It will prompt to select MySQL version to install. Select the MySQL 5.7 option to install on your system.

Refer below link for steps to install it.

[https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-on-debian-10-buster/#:~:text=You%20can%20download%20and%20install,below%20command%20to%20enable%20PPA.&text=During%20the%20installation%20of%20MySQL,to%20install%20on%20your%20system](https://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-on-debian-10-buster/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20download%20and%20install,below%20command%20to%20enable%20PPA.&text=During%20the%20installation%20of%20MySQL,to%20install%20on%20your%20system).